# How to handle timezone offset when parsing date in Python?

Tags: python, parsing, datetime, timezone-offset

I was looking at [this reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) but couldn't find how to handle the timezone offset (e.g. `+0200`) when parsing a string into date in Python.

My date string example is `Thu Apr 17 10:50:39 2014 +0200`.

If it were just `Thu Apr 17 10:50:39 2014`, the pattern `%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y` when using `datetime.strptime`.

Can I and how do I represent the offset in the date parse pattern?

Answer (score 1):

There is no offset-template in the strptime-function, afaik. You could use dateutils for this one:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
d=parse("Thu Apr 17 10:50:39 2014 +0200")
```